# Can i use another Playstation disc drive in my PS3?

Tags: technical-issues, ps3

I have an older PS3 that has been giving me problems. It has recently stopped reading my game discs, so I decided to take it apart to clean the eye.

Now can't get the disc drive back together! Can I swap the disc drive with another PS that has ring of death?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to ask?

Comment: You can of course exchange any part between any PlayStations (as long as they are the same model or the parts are compatible). The problem lies in whether the drive in the other PlayStation actually works correctly and is not the cause of the failure.

Comment: @mordi2k I don't think so, this seems to be asking about the optical drive, not the hard drive.

Answer (score 2):

If the two disc drives are the same model and the one you are replacing with works, then yes you can perform a swap of the drive.